# R map delimited integers to delimited strings

Tags: r, indexing

### Input

I have the following dataframe (with headers expiry and fruit).

[image]

And I have the follwing vector:

```
index <- c("apple", "kiwi", "banana", "peach", "grape")
```

Where apple = 1, kiwi = 2, banana = 3, peach = 4, grape = 5

### Output

I would like to get the following output.

[image]

How can I solve this ?

### Data source

```
myDf <- structure(list(expiry = 20161212:20161215, fruit = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("2,4", "3,2", "4", "5,3,1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("expiry", 
"fruit"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


index <- c("apple", "kiwi", "banana", "peach", "grape")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply`, `strsplit` and `as.numeric`, `as.character` to create your variable:

```
myDf$fruit2 <- sapply(as.character(myDf$fruit), function(x) 
  paste0(index[as.numeric(strsplit(x, split = ",")[[1]])], collapse = ", "))
```

Comment: Sorry I have one more question. Is this going to work if my index starts at 0 instead 1 ?  So in the column fruit having x_i-1 instead  (4 instead 5 ... 0 instead one).

Comment: If your index begins at 0, it is correct to subtract 0, ie, to have index[as.numeric(.)-1] instead of index[as.numeric()].

Answer (score 2):

a bit more readable in the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data_frame(expiry=c("20161212", "20161213", "20161214", "20161215"),
                 fruit=c("5,3,1", "2,4", "3,2", 4))

index <- c("apple", "kiwi", "banana", "peach", "grape")

by_row(df, function(x) {

  strsplit(x$fruit, ",")[[1]] %>%
    as.numeric() %>%
    map_chr(~index[.]) %>%
    paste0(collapse=",")

}, .collate="cols", .to="fruit_names") %>%
  select(expiry, fruit=fruit_names)
## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##     expiry              fruit
##      <chr>              <chr>
## 1 20161212 grape,banana,apple
## 2 20161213         kiwi,peach
## 3 20161214        banana,kiwi
## 4 20161215              peach
```